# PERMISSION_DENIED with External Account when using BetaAnalyticsDataClient get ga4 data

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-analytics-4

Our service aims to assist users in retrieving GA4 data for the purpose of calculating ROAS. The actual processing flow is outlined below:

Firstly, I set up the Google Client:

```
$this->googleClient = new Google_Client();
$scopes = [
    Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY,
    Google_Service_Oauth2::USERINFO_EMAIL,
];
$this->googleClient->setAuthConfig($googleOAuthFile);
$this->googleClient->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
$this->googleClient->setScopes($scopes);
$this->googleClient->setAccessType('offline');
$this->googleClient->setApprovalPrompt("force");

$this->googleClient->createAuthUrl(); // Retrieve authorization code
```

After obtaining the authorization code, I proceed to obtain the token:

```
$token = $this->googleClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($code);
// And save the token
```

Allow users to select the property ID from the list of properties they have access to.

```
$admin = new Google_Service_GoogleAnalyticsAdmin($this->googleClient);
$accounts = $admin->accountSummaries->listAccountSummaries()->accountSummaries;

foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    foreach ($account->propertySummaries as $property) {
        $propertyId = substr($property->property, strrpos($string, '/') + 1);
        $propertyIds[] = $propertyId;
    }
}
// Then let users choice one property from $propertyIds
```

When I want to retrieve data, I use the token to access the data:

```
$token = $this->refreshTokenIfExpired($token); // Works fine here

$clientAuthFileData = json_decode(file_get_contents($googleOAuthFile), true);
$credentials = [
    'type'          => 'authorized_user',
    'client_id'     => $clientAuthFileData['web']['client_id'],
    'client_secret' => $clientAuthFileData['web']['client_secret'],
    'refresh_token' => $token,
];

// Utilize the Google Analytics Data API (GA4)
$analyticsClient = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
    'credentials' => $credentials,
]);

// Encounter failure at this stage
$analyticsClient->runReport([
    'property' => "properties/{$propertyIdGetFromUser}",
    // Other parameters
]);
```

The error received is as follows:

```
{
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permissions for this property. To learn more about Property ID, see https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/property-id.",
    "code": 7,
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": []
}
```

To address this issue, I have attempted the following:

1. This error occurs on the production server but works fine locally.
2. I have swapped the two googleOAuthFile instances, but the issue
   persists.
3. On the production server, I have certified my app, and the
   publishing status is "In production," with the user type set as
   "External."

Is there any other troubleshooting step or solution you would recommend? I sincerely appreciate your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

> User does not have sufficient permissions for this property.

Means exactly that the user who is authenticating the application does not have aceess to the property you are trying to access in your code.

If you run your app as example@myCompanyDomain.net you obviously have access as its your account.   If i try to run your app I don't have access to your account so like other@gmail.com I wont be able to access your private data.

In order to allow other@gmail.com to access your google analytics data your going to have to go in though the admins section of the google analytics account and grant other@gmail.com access.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  
However, if possible, what I'm looking for is the possibility of accessing ga4 data for a specific property ID via user authorization and provided, similar to what can be done with Universal Analytics. Therefore, I cannot use the "grant other@gmail.com access" method since it is not feasible for me to handle this for every individual user.
Is there an alternative solution or approach that would allow me to achieve this goal?
I appreciate your assistance and guidance.

Comment: if you are only accessing an account that you the developer control then you should be using a service account

Comment: I would like to access the ga4 resources of users who are utilizing my application, rather than accessing my own resources.

Comment: What I aim to do is collect, organize, and calculate the Return on Advertising Spend (ROAS) data for my users. This is a service we provide to them.

Comment: then you need to use Oauth2 and request access to their account.

Comment: Yes, I have attempted to do so.
I tried following the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69544249/switch-from-google-service-analyticsreporting-google-apiclient-sdk-to-betaanal). 
However, I encountered an issue: It only works as expected with internal email addresses (example@myCompanyDomain.net), but not with external ones (other@gmail.com).

Comment: edit your question and include your code.     you need to be sure you are listening other@gmail.com accounts sounds like you are trying to access a Static profile

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you please assist me once again? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: $propertyIdGetFromUser  <--- the error message means thats wrong.  I would do a list of accounts the user has access to and show them that and let them pick from it.

Comment: I let users choose from a list they have access to. I'm sorry that my question missed this part, I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

Figure this out by using [Google Analytics Data API (GA4)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport), instead of google/analytics-data SDK.

For anyone else who runs into this you can use this:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', [API_URL], [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . [ACCESS_TOKEN],
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'json' => $data,
]);

$result = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```